# ERROR Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.2.Final:dev (default-cli) on project code-with-quarkus:

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin

when I use the command mvn clean quarkus: dev, I get the following response from the terminal in intellij:

```
E:\api-hard-lot>mvn clean quarkus:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< org.acme:code-with-quarkus >---------------------
[INFO] Building code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\api-hard-lot\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.2.Final:dev (default-cli) @ code-with-quarkus ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to E:\api-hard-lot\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.052 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-25T12:02:55-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.2.Final:dev (default-cli) on project code-with-quarkus: Fatal error
compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

'cmd' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project was created using JDK 11 and thus mandates JDK 11 while you are trying to build it with a JDK inferior to 11.

Either update your JDK (recommended) or adjust your project to be JDK 8 compatible (replace occurrences of 11 with 1.8 in your pom file).

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys thats exactly my solution i alter to jdk 8 and

in pom
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
and
in code-with-quarkus